# Game Development in .NET (VB specifically) circa 2012/2013 and Performance vs C++

Tags: .net, vb.net, game-engine

So with Microsoft's new version of Visual Studios was released fairly recently and they seemed to have added some performance increases. Also hardware is increasing in power and I was curious:

Would a game developed in VB .NET run fast enough for users to not notice a difference between a C++ developed game?

Comment: Hey, downvoter, you could at least drop a comment (noticing it's already +2)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the type of game; in a simple 2D board game, for example, rendering and calculations aren't complicated, and it's unlikely user will see any difference. If the game needs to render responsive 3D graphics in real time, there will always be a difference. Or with complicated AI (like in chess, for example) - the high amounts of data will certainly slow down VB program a little, because of garbage collected memory. Still, you never know until you actually measure.

I've recently read an article about managed languages performance, and how JIT can sometimes be even better than ahead-of-time compiler optimizations, but I forgot where it was. I guess it's googleable; you might want to take a look at it and at JIT optimizations in general (remember that both VB and C# compile to IL, which is then interpreted).

Comment: You can read this [Article](http://code4k.blogspot.co.nz/2011/03/benchmarking-cnet-direct3d-11-apis-vs.html) and see some differences between managed languages DX11 APIs and native C++ performance.

Comment: One small but significant point: VB/C# are compiled to IL, which is then JIT'ed to native code - not interpreted.

Comment: JIT can only occur after at least one run of non-optimized code, IIRC. So it has to be interpreted *first*. Plus, i highly doubt that the whole JIT process is so fast that we could skip it - it causes some initial overhead.

Comment: @Bartek you are correct the code is jitted the first time the function is ran (hence Just In Time).  However, using the NGEN tool provided by microsoft you can take your assembly and generate a Native Image from it.  When it comes to type of thing I would suggest put a test case together and measure

Comment: Its also worth mentioning that microsoft has XNA which is a managed game framework you might to take a look at

Comment: I'll look at the stuff you've mentioned and possibly improve my answer when I have time, thanks!

Comment: @iamkrillin Worth noting that XNA is no longer being developed

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a first-person shooter in C# using [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com/) for OpenGL/OpenAL bindings and it's going pretty well so far. There are a few potential pitfalls, and there will always be some measurable speed difference between JITted IL and C++, but if you're careful you can minimize that difference to the point where it wouldn't be noticable to an end user.

Offload as much work as you can to the GPU. Vertex processing CPU side will kill your framerate if you're not careful, especially with animation and particle effects. Work on the GPU is identical in speed to a C++ game (although the method calls may make it a tad bit more expensive, so try to use VBOs/VAOs/etc.)

Profile your game regularly. Check for how many objects are being allocated per frame and try to reduce the number of allocations and, ideally, offset all allocation to initialization. Additionally, don't be afraid to use an `unsafe` block in tight math loops that are bottlenecking your game. Use object pools to help you reduce allocation while running the game.

If you need 3d physics, I've found that [Jitter Physics Engine](http://jitter-physics.com/wordpress/) is very good about not generating a lot of garbage at runtime and uses object pools for when it has to.